# running java main class using subprocess.Popen in python

Tags: java, python, subprocess

I want to execute java main class `main.java` by python using `subprocess.Popen()`. `main.java` takes 3 args.

I wonder how to do it? For example I have a `HelloWorld.java` class:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!" + args[0]);
    } }
```

I tried to call it in python using the command:

> print (subprocess.Popen('java C:/Users/testing/Hello.Main sayHello',
>   shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())

where 'sayHello' is the string args I want to pass in. It said

**Error: Could not find or load main class C:.Users.testing.Hello.Main**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run your java file with extension `.class` the following way:

```
java your.path.Main arg1 arg2
```

where,

- `java` - command, which runs the Java interpreter
- `your.path.Main` - full name of your class (without `.class`)
- `arg1 arg2` - the arguments (written by spaces or between `"`)

Further, when you formatted this line, it transmits in `subprocess.Popen()` as argument.

```
subprocess.Popen('java your.path.Main arg1 arg2')
```

I'm not Python programmer, because I advice you to read [documentation about this method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: note: it won't work on POSIX systems; use a list argument instead: `'java your.path.Main arg1 arg2'.split()`

Comment: I tried it with simple helloworld class using: `print (subprocess.Popen('java C:/Users/Testing/src/HelloWorld.Main', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())` and got the error: **Error: Could not find or load main class C:.Users.src.Hello**

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I did make `HelloWorld.class` and got that error which is why I don't get the reason :) and thanks for such a fast response

Comment: @AndrewTobilko it works perfectly on command prompt when I was in the correct directory, but doesn't work when I typed in entire path such as `java C:/Users/testing/HelloWorld` it will return same error: Error: Could not find or load main class **C:.Users.testing.HelloWorld** it may be the problem since in python, I also put in full path like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83570/discussion-between-andrew-tobilko-and-hong-le).