# How to execute javascript code from python with arguments

Tags: javascript, python

Executing javascript from python using Naked.toolshed.shell:
[How can I execute JavaScript code from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622385/how-can-i-execute-javascript-code-from-python)
Answered my question fine, But is there any way to do this AND pass an argument through to be executed? like

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js

response = execute_js('file.js', arg1) # arguments to pass
if response.exitcode == 0:
  print(response.stdout)
else:
  sys.stderr.write(response.stderr)
```

while file.js may look something like

```
var x = 10;
x = 10 - arg1; // to pass argument here
console.log(x);
function greet() {
      console.log("Hello World!");
}
greet()
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: try `subprocess` maybe? related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464354/running-java-main-class-using-subprocess-popen-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation reveals, yes it is possible:

> The execute_js() function runs the execute() function on a Node.js script file. Instead of passing the command to be executed as the first parameter, pass a Node.js script filepath as the first parameter and any additional command arguments as the second parameter (optional). The executed command is concatenated from these strings with the following code:

```
if len(arguments) > 0:
    js_command = 'node ' + file_path + " " + arguments
else:
    js_command = 'node ' + file_path
```

> Parameters:
>   file_path (string) - the filepath to the Node.js script that is to be executed by the shell
>
> arguments (string) - optional, any additional arguments to be used with your command

Documentation:
http://naked.readthedocs.io/toolshed_shell.html#Naked.toolshed.shell.execute_js

Comment: Alright I figured it out. The arguments are stored in process.argv. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass an argument(variable) in execute_js('file.js', arg1) it create a problem like value I received in node js command argument is  "NaN"
so to overcome this problem I tried below thing which works fine for me:

First make a string need to pass in execute_js like:

node_cmd = "file.js" + " " + str(variable)
now we can pass node_cmd in execute_js as below:

execute_js("node_cmd")