# How to pass arguments from python to node js using Naked Python library

Tags: python, node.js

I was looking for a way to run node js from python and I found naked and it has really solved my issue. I however have a quick question whose answer I have not been able to find anywhere on the net. So this is what i am trying to do:

I want to run a file 'test.js' with javascript function that takes the argument message

i.e

```
function run_test(message){

   // some code   
}

the argument message however has come come from the python side of things so how do i pass arguments from python and use them in my run_test function 
I found this method:

if len(arguments) > 0:
            js_command = file_path + " " + arguments
        else:
            js_command = file_path
```

> So how can a get the arguments passed from python and use them in my
>   run_test function in javascript

Comment: In my opinion, passing data betweet JS and Python (and back) is best done using json:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Anyways, I think your question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432203/how-to-execute-javascript-code-from-python-with-arguments

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @007fred, maybe i will check out the Json example the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432203/how-to-execute-javascript-code-from-python-with-arguments however does not answer my question it is inconclusive in the sense that it explains how to pass arguments in python but does not show how to actually use these arguments in the JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I think that you already found the solution but for those who is searching, `process.argv` is the answer which is an array where first 2 elements are `node` command and path to your script which you can skip.

So, in JS you should have `const arguments = process.argv.slice(2)`