# Cannot get Bash script output in Celery Worker inside Docker Container

Tags: python, bash, docker, docker-compose, celery

I am literally pulling my hair out over this problem. Recently I have started working on a Remote Code Execution service.

The service sends the following payload to a Celery worker:

```js
{
 "language": "python",
 "code": "print('Hello World!')"
}
```

The service expects to receive back the output of the code.

The Celery worker runs in a docker container, with the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /worker
WORKDIR /worker

COPY requirements.txt /worker/


RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r /worker/requirements.txt

COPY . /worker/
```

For the service and worker I am using ths docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
  api:
    build: app/
    command: uvicorn remote_coding_compilation_engine.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  worker:
    build: worker/
    command: watchmedo auto-restart --directory=./ --pattern=*.py --recursive -- celery --app=worker.celery_app worker -c 2 --loglevel=INFO
    #celery --app=worker.celery_app worker -c 2 --loglevel=INFO
    volumes:
      - ./worker:/worker
    depends_on:
      - api
      - rabbit

  flower:
    image: mher/flower
    command: ["flower", "--broker=pyamqp://guest@rabbit//", "--port=8888"]
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    depends_on:
      - api
      - rabbit
      - worker
```

The worker creates a *.py* file with the code given in the payload and then runs a bash script to execute the code, the code output should be automatically redirected to an *out_file* from python. However I am not able to get the output of the bash script.

This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo "No code running command provided!"
else
    eval $@
fi
```

I am passing the follwoing arguments to this script: `python path_to_file`

This is the worker code which runs the bash script:

```
def execute_code(cls, command: str, out_file_path: str) -> None:
        """
        Function which execudes the given command and outputs the result in the given out_file_path

        @param command: command to be executed
        @param out_file_path: path to the output file

        @return None

        @raise: FileNotFoundError if the command does not exist
        @raise: IOError if the output file cannot be created
        @raise: CalledProcessError if the command fails to be executed
        """
        try:
            logging.info(f"Creating output file: {out_file_path}")
            with open(out_file_path, "w+") as out_file_desc:

                logging.info(f"Creating process with command: {command} and output_file: {out_file_path}")
                os.chmod(cls.EXECUTE_CODE_SCRIPT_PATH, 0o755)

                rc = subprocess.call(command, shell=True, stdout=out_file_desc, stderr=out_file_desc)

                logging.info(f"Commandmd: {command.split()}")
                logging.info(f"Return Code: {rc}")
                logging.info(f"OutFile Content: {out_file_desc.read()}")

                if rc != 0:
                    logging.debug(f"Command execution was errored: {out_file_desc.read()}")
                    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(rc, command)

        except FileNotFoundError as fnf:
            logging.error(
                f"Command not found: {command}"
            )
            raise fnf
        except IOError as ioe:
            logging.error(
                f"Could not create output file: {out_file_path}"
            )
            raise ioe
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
            logging.error(
                f"Process exited with error: {cpe.output}"
            )
            raise cpe
```

Obs1. The command to be executed in `subprocess.call` is in the form `/worker/execute_code/code_execute.sh python /worker/tmp/in_files/some_file_name.py`

Obs2. I am sure the script runs the command since, for example if I alter the path to folder containing the code to be executed I am getting a "FileNotFound" error.

Obs3. If instead of "$@" I am using literally python <<hardcoded_path>>, I can see the output of the bash script

Obs4. The running entity has rw access on the output file. I cannot get the output of the script even if I use the default stdout

What I've tried:

- Firstly I didn't want to use a bash script, I wanted to use subprocess.run, but again I was unable to get the output
- If I call the script using the terminal, I get the code output

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were right in your initial intuition to not have to maintain a bash file at all. If I understand correctly what you're trying to do (execute the command, write the output to a file), this does that without maintaining a bash script or writing the command to an input file to begin with:

```
def execute_code(command="print('Hello World')", out_file_path='/home/geo/result.txt'):
    with open(out_file_path, 'w+') as f:
        subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", command], stdout=f)
```

You should see the output in `result.txt`.

Comment: This is working and it is very close to what I need, but this is only working for python, in the future I'd like to add other programming languages such C++/Java

Comment: you have the variable "language": "python" which you can use to map to different languages entrypoints. "laguage": "c++" -> subprocess.Popen(["g++",  command], stdout=f). If instead you want to pass the entire via the command parameter you could use result = subprocess.run(PIPE) and result.stdout / result.stderr

Comment: Oh, OK. Scaling to other languages is a different issue than the original one, it seems to me. There are multiple ways you could accomplish that. But in line with my answer you can run Java, for example, in a `subprocess.Popen()` like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464854/4038362

Again, getting this to work and scaling it seem two different Qs to me.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue. I have been doing things correctly, having the same idea as @Paul. The problem was actually a process race condition. Before the "exeucte_code" method, I had another method which would create an in_file containing the code to be run. The issue was that the process executing the Popen command would always find the file to be empty, because the process creating the file wouldn't write to the file "fast_Enough". Using flush on the process creating the in file, solved the issue. Thank you :D